# Evernote user AUTH_EXPIRED but still receiving webhook transactions

Tags: c#, webhooks, evernote

I have a C# service that authenticates users with Evernote using OAuth. I also have a webhook configured with Evernote that receives a transaction every time a user (that has authorized my service with Evernote) creates or updates a note.

I'm seeing an issue where Evernote throws the "AUTH_EXPIRED" error, however I am still receiving transactions from the webhook for that user.

If a user's auth has expired, should I no longer receive transactions for them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I believe you will be getting webhooks regardless of the expiration unless the user explicitly revokes the tokens.